# Looping over .tar folder to go multilevel extraction

Tags: java

I have a `.tar` directory and inside that again `.tar.gz` directory and within that `.gz` or `.tar` folder/files my or may not be available.
I want to keep checking and extract this **till 10 level deeper**.

It means extract the .tar folder, found `.tar.gz`, again go on till the end and extract it.

I am able to do till 1 level using apache commons that is .tar if i am extracting, i am able to see `.tar.gz` file at destination folder.

My concern is how to loop in this logic to check till ten level deeper and extract it.

Comment: Search for untar or extract tar in java.

Comment: Sorry but I have already explored and then posted here. I found the answer till one level of extraction as if its .tar.gz or .tar file then extract it.But if there is nested .tar or .tar.gz inside directory available then I didnt find any relevant suggestion. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So your question is how to allow up to ten levels of recursion. How about this?

```
void unarchive(File archive, File targetDirectory) {
    unarchive(File archive, File targetDirectory, 10);
}

void unarchive(File archive, File targetDirectory, int depth) {
    // perform your unarchive that you have anyway

    if (depth>0) {
        // loop over extracted files. If you have any kind of archive, then
        unarchive(foundarchive, new File(targetDirectory, foundarchive.getName()), depth-1);
    }
}
```